# How to respond with appropriate error message through an API response to request made using Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, postman

I created One restful Api which has all the crud operations. when i am testing get employee By id i am not able to display error message. even though i am throwing exception when record not exists for that id.

Here is My Controller code...

```
    @GetMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") long employeeId) throws ResourceNotFoundException{

        Employee employee=service.getEmployeeById(employeeId).orElseThrow(()->new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :"+employeeId));

        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
```

and My Exception class code

```
package com.mystyle.exception;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

and my postman error message

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-19T06:21:10.172+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/v1/employee/2"
}
```

Comment: Does your exception throw in the stack trace?

Comment: Is your question, is that you wanted to show custom error message with appropriate HTTP error? If you are using custom exception.

Suggesting you to see this post :https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class for Error message under the model package.

> ```
>  public class ErrorMessage {
>
>   private String errorMessage;
>   private int errorCode;
>   private String documentation;
>   public ErrorMessage() {
>
>   }
>   public ErrorMessage(String errorMessage, int errorCode, String documentation) {
>       this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
>       this.errorCode = errorCode;
>       this.documentation = documentation;
>   }
>   public String getErrorMessage() {
>       return errorMessage;
>   }
>   public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
>       this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
>   }
>   public int getErrorCode() {
>       return errorCode;
>   }
>   public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
>       this.errorCode = errorCode;
>   }
>   public String getDocumentation() {
>       return documentation;
>   }
>   public void setDocumentation(String documentation) {
>       this.documentation = documentation;
>   }
>
>    }
> ```

2.Create a Custome Exception class under the exception package and generate Serial Version UID.

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2491065979792776613L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String msg)
    {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

3.Create a ExceptionHandler class under the exception package

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ResourceNotFoundExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> toResponse(ResourceNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage=new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage(),404,"www.benz.com");

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(errorMessage,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```